# Check all available files on a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm building a gem, which contains a CSS file. And I want to `include` it inside my code.

I am trying to make the correct import, but I'm not getting to it.

Is there a way that I can "debug" the project that includes my gem so I can check for every available file inside RAILS_ROOT to see where my SCSS file is? For that matter, is there an easy way to find out in the Rails console where a file is (or should) be located?

Answer (score 0):

Gems can be stored on your system in a large number of possible locations, depending on any version manager that is installed, or permissions of your directories, or on the contents of your `Gemfile`.

The quickest way to find the location of the installed `gem` on your system is probably to use the `gem which` command e.g.:

```
jadams@Temp046317:~/code/ais-lims$ gem which advantage
/home/jadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/advantage-0.1.2/lib/advantage.so
```

from there you should be able to locate all the files in the `gem`

however, as with a locally hosted version of a gem, (using `path`) it doesn't always return a sensible answer:

```
jadams@Temp046317:~/code/data-extract$ grep -i svg-graph Gemfile
# gem 'svg-graph', git: "https://github.com/lumean/svg-graph2"
gem 'svg-graph', path: '/home/xxx/code/svg-graph2'
jadams@Temp046317:~/code/data-extract$ gem which svg-graph
ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library svg-graph
```

from within Rails, you might find it easier to get the `GEM_HOME` environment variable, then look at the sub-dirs from there.

```
ENV['GEM_HOME']
```

Comment: I explained myself incorrectly, I want to verify in the project that I am adding my gem into where the files are located.

Comment: @Lomefin hopefully this answer better suits, in that case?